# Router Hanging in Dealer-Router Setup

Tags: scala, zeromq

Given the following attempt to connect 1 `DEALER` to 1 `ROUTER`:

```
package net.async

import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Client {
  val Empty           = "".getBytes
  def message(x: Int) = s"HELLO_#$x".getBytes
  val Count   = 5
}

class Client(name: String) extends Runnable {

  import Client._
  import AsyncClientServer.Port

  override def run(): Unit = {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val dealer = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
    dealer.setIdentity(name.getBytes)
    dealer.connect(s"tcp://localhost:$Port")
    runHelper(dealer, Count)
  }

  @tailrec
  private def runHelper(dealer: Socket, count: Int): Unit = {
    dealer.send(dealer.getIdentity, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
    dealer.send(Empty,              ZMQ.SNDMORE)
    dealer.send(message(count),     0)
    println(s"Dealer: ${dealer.getIdentity} received message: " + dealer.recv(0))
    runHelper(dealer, count - 1)
  }
}

object AsyncClientServer {

  val Port = 5555

  val context = ZMQ.context(1)
  val router = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    router.bind(s"tcp://*:$Port")
    mainHelper()
    new Thread(new Client("Joe")).start()
  }

  private def mainHelper(): Unit = {
    println("Waiting to receive messages from Dealer.")
    val identity = router.recv(0)
    val empty    = router.recv(0)
    val message  = router.recv(0)

    println(s"Router received message, ${new String(message)} from sender: ${new String(identity)}.")
    mainHelper()
  }
}
```

I see the following output, hanging on the second message.

```
[info] Running net.async.AsyncClientServer
[info] Waiting to receive messages from Dealer.
```

Why is that?

Comment: @drozzy - you were right about `mainHelper`'s blocking. I needed to move that line **after** the `new Thread(new Client(...))` call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its the cause of your problem but you don't need to send the identity frame from your dealer, zeromq will do this for you. By adding it your actually sending a 4 part message.

```
IDENTITY
IDENTITY
EMPTY
CONTENT
```

Comment: It will append identity and empty die to Dealer sender or Router receiver?

Comment: Actually, answering when half asleep was bad. The dealer does need to append the empty frame (and any previous routing info that it had, nothing in your case) but NOT its own identity. That will be added by the router socket receiving the message.

Comment: But the `ROUTER`, when speaking to the `DEALER`, must send a 3-frame message: `[IDENTITY][EMPTY][MESSAGE]`?. Also - care to edit your answer, please?

Comment: Edited answer. And yes, the router needs to send the address frame(s), empty frame, then content frame(s).