# DEALER to ROUTER - out of order messages

Tags: scala, zeromq

As a follow-up to [ROUTER to DEALER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841182/router-hanging-in-dealer-router-setup/38862267#38862267), I have a single `DEALER`'s talking to a single `ROUTER`:

In short, I create 2 threads for each `DEALER`. The life-cycle of the `DEALER` is:

1. send `READY` to `ROUTER` to indicate that `ROUTER` can trust `KILL` signals from it
2. wait for ACK from `ROUTER`
3. send 5 messages
4. send `END` message so that `ROUTER` will exit

   package net.async

   ```
   import org.zeromq.ZMQ
   import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket

   import scala.annotation.tailrec

   object Client {
     val Empty           = "".getBytes
     def message(x: Int) = s"HELLO_#$x".getBytes
     val Count   = 5
   }

   class Client(name: String) extends Runnable {

     import Client._
     import AsyncClientServer._

     override def run(): Unit = {
       val context = ZMQ.context(1)
       val dealer = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
       dealer.setIdentity(name.getBytes)
       dealer.connect(s"tcp://localhost:$Port")
       initiate(dealer)
     }

     private def initiate(dealer: Socket): Unit = {
       dealer.send("".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
       dealer.send("READY".getBytes, 0)
       val reply = new String(dealer.recv(0))
       println(s"DEALER: ${new String(dealer.getIdentity)} received $reply")
       if(reply == Ack) {println("DEALER: received ACK!"); runHelper(dealer, Count)}
       else              initiate(dealer)
     }

     @tailrec
     private def runHelper(dealer: Socket, count: Int): Unit = {
       val msg = if(count <= 0 ) End.getBytes else message(count)
       dealer.send(msg, 0)
       val id = new String(dealer.getIdentity)
       println(s"DEALER ${id} sent message: ${new String(msg)}.")
       // println(s"Dealer: ${dealer.getIdentity} received message: " + new String(dealer.recv(0)))
       runHelper(dealer, count - 1)
     }
   }

   object AsyncClientServer {

     val End = "END"
     val Ack = "WORLD"
     val Port = 5555
     val ClientReady = "READY"
     val Empty = "".getBytes

     val context = ZMQ.context(1)
     val router  = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER)

     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       router.bind(s"tcp://*:$Port")
       new Thread(new Client("JOE")).start()
       //new Thread(new Client("JILL")).start()
       mainHelper(List.empty)
     }

     private def mainHelper(activeClients: List[String]): Unit = {
       val identity = new String( router.recv(0) )
       println(s"ROUTER: Received message from $identity.")
       val empty   = router.recv(0)
       println("ROUTER: received empty: " + new String(empty))
       val message = new String( router.recv(0) )
       println(s"ROUTER: received message: $message")

       checkMessage(identity, message, activeClients) match {
         case Normal(msg)     => mainHelper(activeClients)
         case Ready(id)       => ackDealer(router, id); mainHelper(id :: activeClients)
         case Kill            => sys.exit(0)
         case UnknownIdentity => mainHelper(activeClients)
       }
     }

     private def ackDealer(router: Socket, identity: String): Unit = {
       router.send(identity.getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
       router.send(Empty,             ZMQ.SNDMORE)
       router.send(Ack.getBytes,      0)
     }

     private def checkMessage(identity: String, message: String, activeClients: List[String]): Message = {
       if(message == ClientReady) Ready(identity)
       else {
         activeClients.find(_ == identity) match {
           case Some(_) =>
             if (message == End) Kill
             else                Normal(message)
           case None    =>       UnknownIdentity
         }
       }
     }
     sealed trait Message
     case class Normal(value: String) extends Message
     case class Ready(id: String)     extends Message
     case object Kill                 extends Message
     case object UnknownIdentity extends Message

   }
   ```

However, it appears that the `ROUTER` is receiving messages out of order:

```
[info] Running net.async.AsyncClientServer
[info] ROUTER: Received message from JOE.
[info] ROUTER: received empty:
[info] ROUTER: received message: READY
[info] DEALER: JOE received
[info] DEALER: JOE received WORLD
[info] DEALER: received ACK!
[info] ROUTER: Received message from JOE.
[info] ROUTER: received empty:
[info] ROUTER: received message: READY
[info] DEALER JOE sent message: HELLO_#5.
[info] DEALER JOE sent message: HELLO_#4.
[info] DEALER JOE sent message: HELLO_#3.
[info] DEALER JOE sent message: HELLO_#2.
[info] ROUTER: Received message from JOE.
[info] DEALER JOE sent message: HELLO_#1.
[info] ROUTER: received empty: HELLO_#5
```

The last `[info]` shows that `ROUTER` received `HELLO_#5` for what should've been an empty. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `initiate` you correctly send an empty frame then the content

```
dealer.send("".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
dealer.send("READY".getBytes, 0)
```

However in `runHelper` you only send the content

```
dealer.send(msg, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, David. After making that change, I see that the `ROUTER` eventually terminates, whereas it did not in my code. However, after making that change, I see an overwhelming amount of `END` messages from 2 `DEALER` Clients before the `ROUTER` receives one, and, consequently, terminates. See this gist please - https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/a29946348a27d904659de1cca8819d2f. Why does this happen, i.e. I expected a single `END` to prompt the `ROUTER` to receive it, and then terminate.

Comment: Remember that when `send` returns the message has not actually been sent, its just been queued for sending. As your sending the messages in a tight loop (no other processing happening) you'll likely be queuing a lot of messages before any have been received at the other end.